# Does geth have to sync before getting public data?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I started a `geth` node, passed in the ABI and ran `contractInstance = MyContract.at('..')`.

Then when I ran `contractInstance.somePublicVariable(123)` I am seeing 0 values everywhere.

Is this because my geth node hasn't synced with this public contract? Does my geth node need to sync if its in fast syncmode? Or does it just ask peers for this data? What about in light syncmode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a full or fast sync, your node needs to sync past the block in which your contract was deployed before it can start accessing it.

In a light sync, the node you are connected to must have synced past the block in which your contract was deployed.